# Reset TextBoxWatermarkExtender by Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

I have a TextBoxWatermarkExtender. But when set null or clear the value of text box by jQuery watermark is not coming up.So how to clear the textbox values so that watermark will show up.
Here is the code

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
function ImgcloseButton_onclick() {    
$("#txtChildFirstName").val('');
$("#txtChildFirstName").val("");
$("#txtChildFirstName").val(null);
}
</script>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtChildFirstName" runat="server" TabIndex="14" CssClass="registrationTextBoxes" ToolTip="min. 3 characters"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="txtWaterChildFirstName" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtChildFirstName" WatermarkText="Min. 3 characters" WatermarkCssClass="txtWatermarked" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. I need to switch the css class of TextBox to the watermark css and set default value for textbox..